# Коннект Django с существующей БД mysql

Tags: mysql, python, django, mvc

Подскажите, привязал  django проект к уже заполненой данными бд mysql. Вопрос по моделям, если у меня имеется в бд таблица Sales и я создам модель  Sales, то есть ли риск затереть существующую таблицу? Как в данном случае отработает логика модели?

Answer (score 4):

Нашел решение на свой вопрос, думаю остальным поможет.

```
'python manage.py inspectdb' создаст классы по всем существующим таблицам бд. 
'python manage.py inspectdb > models.py'сохранит все классы в модель.
```

[Подробности](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/legacy-databases/)

Comment: На вопросы «есть ли риск затереть существующую таблицу» и «Как в данном случае отработает логика модели» здесь ответа нет)

Comment: если таблица есть, то создана не будет, риск при миграциях, когда уже была инициализация.

Comment: В общем данные все сохранились в таблицах, однако джанго добавил свои стандартные таблицы в БД (сессии, миграции и тд). Попробовал в shell вывести данные из ранее созданных таблиц - все выводится корректно.

Comment: @Zireael, если нужно чтобы джанго не "мусорил" нужно отключить все лишнее или подключать как вторую базу данных, тогда весь "мусор" будет в первой базе. Также если от джанго нужно было только orm, то есть более простые способы работы.

Answer (score 0):

Лучше не рисковать и написать свои модели как тебе удобно и создать новую базу а потом подконектиться к заполненной базе и прочитать все. И уже заполнить свою базу теми что прочитал. Тебе просто нужно будет создать новые объекты и всё.

Comment: На вопрос не ответили, таки какой риск-то?

Comment: Опиши модель и пробуй читать из базы без выполнения migrate. В таком случае риска нет

Comment: Если ты опишешь модель и ошибешся с параметрами то есть не нулевой риск потери данных